# resampling timeseries data using a single column as a pivot

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a large DataFrame with multi-layered headers, and a DateTimeIndex in 1-minute samples. Here is a small extract of it:

```
                     Lmax                                            
                     8000     A  31.5    63   125   250   500  1000  2000   
Night idx                                                                   
2023-01-20 23:00:00  31.9  69.3  67.0  69.1  67.0  61.6  63.3  66.9  63.3   
2023-01-20 23:01:00  37.2  70.0  67.6  70.8  68.7  66.6  66.8  67.0  64.4   
2023-01-20 23:02:00  27.6  65.6  68.7  65.8  58.4  59.1  61.2  63.5  58.9   
2023-01-20 23:03:00  41.1  71.7  79.0  79.2  75.6  75.4  68.0  65.5  64.0   
2023-01-20 23:04:00  35.8  67.0  73.9  69.6  62.3  63.9  63.8  65.4  59.2   
2023-01-20 23:05:00  36.5  68.7  75.6  77.9  75.8  69.6  64.8  65.7  61.2   
2023-01-20 23:06:00  40.9  70.3  77.7  77.3  68.4  63.8  65.5  67.8  63.8   
2023-01-20 23:07:00  42.8  69.3  76.3  77.2  68.5  66.2  64.9  65.6  63.3   
2023-01-20 23:08:00  48.2  79.0  72.8  72.4  70.2  70.4  70.7  68.7  70.5   
2023-01-20 23:09:00  32.5  69.1  74.3  71.8  63.4  64.4  67.2  65.1  62.7
```

What I want to do is resample the data to 2 minutes, using the max values in ("Lmax", "A") as a pivot. So, I want the maximum value from each 2-minute period in ("Lmax", "A"), and then the corresponding data from all other columns for that same row. Simply using groupby or resample with max() won't work, as that will take the max values from **each** column for each 2-minute period, which is not what I want.

The answer should look something like this:

```
                     Lmax                                            
                     8000     A  31.5    63   125   250   500  1000  2000   
Night idx                                                                   
2023-01-20 23:00:00  37.2  70.0  67.6  70.8  68.7  66.6  66.8  67.0  64.4  
2023-01-20 23:02:00  41.1  71.7  79.0  79.2  75.6  75.4  68.0  65.5  64.0      
2023-01-20 23:04:00  36.5  68.7  75.6  77.9  75.8  69.6  64.8  65.7  61.2    
2023-01-20 23:06:00  40.9  70.3  77.7  77.3  68.4  63.8  65.5  67.8  63.8    
2023-01-20 23:08:00  48.2  79.0  72.8  72.4  70.2  70.4  70.7  68.7  70.5
```

I have tried various different combinations of groupbys, resamples, idxmax etc., but can't get it working. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the indices corresponding to maximum values in the `(Lmax, A)` column per 2 min interval then use these indices to reindex the dataframe

```
ix = df[('Lmax', 'A')].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2min')).idxmax()
result = df.loc[ix].set_index(ix.index)
```

---

```
Lmax                 Lmax                                                
Night idx            8000     A  31.5    63   125   250   500  1000  2000
2023-01-20 23:00:00  37.2  70.0  67.6  70.8  68.7  66.6  66.8  67.0  64.4
2023-01-20 23:02:00  41.1  71.7  79.0  79.2  75.6  75.4  68.0  65.5  64.0
2023-01-20 23:04:00  36.5  68.7  75.6  77.9  75.8  69.6  64.8  65.7  61.2
2023-01-20 23:06:00  40.9  70.3  77.7  77.3  68.4  63.8  65.5  67.8  63.8
2023-01-20 23:08:00  48.2  79.0  72.8  72.4  70.2  70.4  70.7  68.7  70.5
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I have tried. For some reason, it works with a fresh DataFrame, but not when I have one returned by another method of my class. I have tried creating a deep copy, but still no luck, and can't see any obvious difference between that and a fresh DataFrame. The idxmax() line is returning "ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence"

Comment: I should note that the groupby.max() method works fine, it's just the idxmax() that is returning a ValueError, stating that the sequence is empty.

Comment: Just found this bug report. I think this is probably affecting me, as there are large periods of time missing from the DF I am trying to operate on, but it works fine on a fresh DF with no periods missing. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47350